# php search function dynamically show results with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, search

I have the following php script which works fine, it uses the search term and compares it with a few different fields, then prints out the each record that matches:

```
<?php

mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());  

mysql_select_db ("table"); 

$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';

$sql = mysql_query("select * from asset where 
                             name like '%$search%' or 
                             barcode like '%$search%' or
                             serial like '%$search%' ");  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  

    echo '<br/> Name: '.$row['name'];
    echo '<br/> Barcode: '.$row['barcode'];
    echo '<br/> Serial: '.$row['serial']; 

    }

?>
```

And this is the form that links to it:

```
<form action="http://localhost/test/search.php" method="post">
 Search: <input type="text" name="search" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I need to some how encode the results of the search so I can use them in a javascript function, then I can display them on the same html page below the form.

Comment: `AJAX` (+`JSON`) is what you need

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to use `AJAX`. You can send data back to the same page using `JSON`.

**Advice** - Don't use mysql_* functions since they are deprecated. Learn mysqli_* and try using that.

```
<script>
$(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();

   $("form").on('submit', function(){
       var form = $(this);
       var url = form.attr('action');
       var data = form.serialize();

       $.post(url, data)
       .done(function(response){

            if(response.success == TRUE)
            {
                  // Search result found from json
                  // You have to loop through response.data to display it in your page
                  // Your single loop will have something like below -

                  var name = response.data.name;
                  var barcode = response.data.barcode;
                  var serial = response.data.serial;

                  $("#name").html(name);
                  $("#barcode").html(barcode);
                  $("#serial").html(serial);
            }
            else
            {
                  // search result not found
            }

       });
   });
});
</script>
```

On **`search.php`**

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("table");
$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';

$sql = mysql_query("select * from asset where 
                         name like '%$search%' or 
                         barcode like '%$search%' or
                         serial like '%$search%' ");

$num = mysql_rows_nums($sql);

$json = array();
if($num > 0)
{
    $json['success'] = TRUE;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
      $json['data']['name'] = $row['name'];
      $json['data']['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
      $json['data']['serial'] = $row['serial'];
    }
}
else
{
    $json['success'] = FALSE;
}

return json_encode($json);
```

?>

Comment: The question doesn't have `jQuery` tag

Comment: You might have forgotten jquery library to include -  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You have to prevent default submit action by calling `preventDefault()` method in `submit` handler

Comment: It's half working, I can see in firebug that it's sending to search.php however it's not getting a response

Comment: Try debugging the return $json. Replace `return json_encode($json);` with this  `echo <pre>; print_r($json); exit;` and see what you get in firebug.`